# Regular Expression differences between [] and ()

Tags: php, design-patterns, expression

How to understand about this Pattern?

```
/^((?:\+?61)|0)(2((3[3789])|(4[0123456789])|(5[012356789])|
(6[0123456789])|[789][0-9])|(3((3[234])|(4[012345789])|(5[0123456789])|
(6[123457])|[789][0-9]))|(7(([23][0-9]|(4[0123456789]))|(5[234567])|
(7[679])))|(8((2[56])|(5[123458])|(6[0123456789])|(7[0123456789])|
(8[0123456789])|(9[0123456789]))))[0-9]{6}$/
```

How the `square bracket[]` and `Parenthesis()` differ from?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: bracket is a range e.g. [A-Z] and parenthesis() denotes a capturing group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[] denotes a character class. () denotes a capturing group.

`[a-z0-9]` -- One character that is in the range of `a-z` OR `0-9`

`(a-z0-9)` -- Explicit capture of a-z0-9. No ranges.

`a` -- Can be captured by `[a-z0-9]`.

`a-z0-9` -- Can be captured by (a-z0-9) and then can be referenced in a replacement and/or later in the expression.

Comment: I cant understand what is explicit capturing